# How to access external HDD from Ubuntu Shell

Tags: ubuntu, python, external-hdd

I'm running Python code on Jupyter notebooks in an Ubuntu shell (I have a Windows PC). I don't have any more space in the PC's internal drive, so I use an external hard drive, but I can't seem to find a way to read files from that HDD to my Ubuntu shell unless I first copy them to the notebooks file, which I don't have space for anymore.

How may I access files on that external HDD?

Comment: By 'windows shell' do you mean https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq Windows Subsystem for Linux? Please click [edit] and amend your original question to show what you are using, then we can provide help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean you're working in a Windows' Ubuntu subsystem. There, you should find the drives known by Windows in `/mnt/letter-of-the-drive`. Keep in mind that in a Windows' Linux subsystem you can't read drives that Windows can't read.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `ls /mnt/d/` for a directory of the root of the external HDD.